# Recommended Castle Windsor/NHibernate stack?

Tags: nhibernate, castle-windsor

I've got a personal (learning) project that uses Castle Windsor (with the NHibernate facility) and NHibernate (and ASP.NET MVC and Moq, and SQL Server 2008, all stuff that I want to learn more about).

I attempted to use [NHibernate Validator](http://nhforge.org/wikis/validator/default.aspx) over the weekend, but it needed the 2.1.0Alpha2 build of [NHibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/343.html).

Since Castle Windsor 1.0RC3 is built against an older version of NHibernate, it all went wrong.

I look on the Castle Windsor site, and the combined installer appears to be deprecated, and none of the components look to have been packaged in a while.

So: what versions of NHibernate and the various Castle components should I be using in my ASP.NET MVC software stack?

Comment: I had the same problem, but then I checked out the trunks of both projects and built them myself - then everything worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should check out [S#arp Architecture](http://groups.google.com/group/sharp-architecture). Comes with a VS project template, has all the binaries you will need to get up and running very quickly.  Uses ASP.NET MVC 1.0, NHibernate 2.0.1 (but 2.1 has been documented and will work), Castle, etc.

It's a great framework.  Awesome documentation and a very helpful user community.

Comment: beware complexity down the line  - when sharp starts to creak - and you have 20 frameworks plugged in that you have little to no understanding of - you're not going to be smiling :)

Answer (score 2):

So far the best options is unfortunately to check out the trunk of Castle, compile and use it that way.

This will be 'fixed' when Castle Windsor gets released (soon ;) ).

Answer (score 2):

I am using the following components :

- NHibernate 2.0.1GA
- NHibernate Validator 1.0.0GA
- Castle Windsor (custom build)

In order to get a version of Castle Windsor & co that matches what NHibernate expects, I checked out revision 5330 of Castle (which is what NH was built against) from their subversion repository and built it.

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Castle [build server](http://builds.castleproject.org/cruise/index.castle). It comes with its own NHibernate files.

Answer (score 1):

What Todd said above. the S#arpe architecture will save you days and days from trying to sort out dependencies manually.

Answer (score 0):

There is also hornget:

- http://code.google.com/p/hornget/

which seems to have died but there is now also Nu:

- http://nu.wikispot.org/

These take out the pain of dependancy hell and get n00bs up and running much faster and with less worry about build versions and all that. There's a sharp learnign curve to all this but the pain is worth it :)

Comment: [nu] ...which died and became NuPack with sponsorship from MS. But then it turned out that was a proein-folding application, so MS is changing its name at the time of writing this comment.